# remoteControlReceivedWithEvent in Swift has superclass error

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to implement a remoteControlWithEvent (in Swift, iOS 9), but I get an error in my App Delegate.

I've got this code below in my viewController, and everything is working flawlessly.

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                print("AVAudioSession is Active")
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
                self.becomeFirstResponder()
```

However, in my AppDelegate, if I try to use the function remoteControlWithEvent,

```
override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent) {
        let rc = event.subtype
        print("does this work? \(rc.rawValue)")
    }
```

I get the error, "Method does not override any method from it's superclass". If I try to take out the override, I get another error...

Let me know if you can help!

-Liam

Comment: What's the other error?

Comment: That's the only error. I'm assuming that I'm not implementing a certain superclass in my App Delegate.

Comment: Yeah, func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent) is a method of UIResponder and AppDelegate is a subclass of UIResponder so you shouldn't get that error. I don't when I add your code to my app delegate. Check your brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually try this:

```
override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent?) {
        let rc = event!.subtype
        print("does this work? \(rc.rawValue)")
    }
```